# Order by Id then by age

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

Ordering list of objects is giving me unwanted result, why can't I order list by id (integer) then by age (integer)? It only orders by Id and when using thenBy after, nothing changes. But when I'm using orderBy name first and thenBy age, it orders list.

```
// Student collection
    IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 
            new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 18 } ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  Age = 15 } ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  Age = 25 } ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 20 } ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron" , Age = 19 } ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 6, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 21 } ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 7, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 25 } ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 8, StudentName = "Bill",  Age = 19 } ,
        };
var thenByResult = studentList.OrderBy(s => s.StudentName).ThenBy(s => s.StudentID).ThenByDescending(s => s.Age);

foreach (var std in thenByResult)
        Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}, Name: {1}, Age:{2}",std.StudentID, std.StudentName, std.Age);
```

If I order by Id then by age I get:

[image]

What I need is age to be ordered by descending order, which in this case it doesn't work at all, only if I remove order thenby student id I get descending order of age, but I don't get the id ordering.

Comment: Subsequent ordering values are used to *tie-break* otherwise equal values. If the id values are unique, they entirely determine the sort order you've asked for, without having to consider age.

Comment: Can you show what order you expect when you first sort by the unique StudentId and then (descending) by Age?

Comment: Please show an example of the order you *wanted* to get, as so far the ways you're describing things perfectly describe how they are meant to work. It sounds like you expected the ordering system to do something other than actually order the items, so please show us what you wanted as a result.

Comment: It is unclear what you require.

Answer (score 2):

You can't order by Age if you are already ordering by StudentId with unique Id.

Comment: Technically you can. You just *don't need to* since it's extra overhead when you know the result is going to be the same.

Comment: Indeed. But what's the point ? you are just slowing down your process

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you rather want to order by descending `Age` first, then by `StudentID`?

```
studentList.OrderByDescending(s => s.Age).ThenBy(s => s.StudentID);
```

The ordering of your example `studentList` would change as follows:

| Original | After ordering by descending `Age` | Then, after ordering by `StudentID` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 18 "John" 2 15 "Steve" 3 25 "Bill" 4 20 "Ram" 5 19 "Ron" 6 21 "Ram" 7 25 "Ram" 8 19 "Bill" | 3 25 "Bill" 7 25 "Ram" 6 21 "Ram" 4 20 "Ram" 5 19 "Ron" 8 19 "Bill" 1 18 "John" 2 15 "Steve" | ...`studentList` will look the same as in the previous column. What it does is ordering each "`Age` group" internally; e.g. ordering the 25-year-olds according to their `StudentID`s (`3`, `7`) and the 19-year-olds according to their `StudentID`s (`5`, `8`). |

If `studentList` were originally *not* ordered by `StudentID`, the resulting order would possibly be different than after ordering by descending `Age`.

Answer (score 0):

There's inconsistencies with the requirements:

1. The title says "order by id then by age" (and assuming that the Id is unique then you shouldn't need to order again after it).
2. The body says what you need is age to be ordered by descending order.
3. The code first orders by student name, then by id, then by age (which again is useless at this point assuming the id is unique).

The assumption is that you want to first sort by age descending, and then if there are multiple students with the same age, they would be sorted by id.

```
var thenByResult = studentList.OrderByDescending(s => s.Age).ThenBy(s => s.StudentID);
```

Answer (score -1):

You firstly sort by `StudentName` field.
And your order is `StudentName` -> `Id` -> `Age` 
To sort only by `Id` and `Age` try this:

```
studentList.OrderBy(s => s.StudentID).ThenByDescending(s => s.Age);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not ordering by `StudentID` and then by `Age` descending, but by `StudentName`, then by `StudentID` and then by `Age`descending.

If you do not want to order by `StudentName`, but only by `StudentID` and `Age`, you need to change your query like this:

```
var thenByResult = studentList.OrderBy(s => s.StudentID).ThenByDescending(s => s.Age);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should order your query like this as you are in need of Age to be in descending order,

```
var thenByResult = studentList.OrderBy(s => s.StudentID).ThenByDescending(s => s.Age);
```

This might do the trick for you.

Answer (score -2):

You change your code from

```
 var thenByResult = studentList.OrderBy(s => s.StudentName).ThenBy(s => s.Age).ThenByDescending(s => s.Age);
```

to

```
var thenByResult = studentList.OrderBy(s => s.StudentName).ThenBy(s => s.Age).ThenByDescending(s => s.Age).ThenBy(s=>s.StudentID);
```

Comment: `ThenBy(s => s.Age).ThenByDescending(s => s.Age)` do you find this in the question?

Comment: @greybeard Look  second paragp "What I need is age to be ordered by descending order,"

Comment: Whatever the merit of ordering by s.Age before by descending s.Age: You  wrote `change from`, I don't find this in the question. Do you?

Comment: in code area, var thenByResult = studentList.OrderBy(s => s.StudentName).ThenBy(s => s.StudentID).ThenByDescending(s => s.Age);